# Mobile Safari - wait until <video> has fully downloaded before playing

Tags: ios, html, video, safari, popcornjs

I'm building a site with a pretty complex `<video>` experience that involves jumping around the video's timeline quite a bit. In order for it to work as smoothly as possible, it's best to not start playing it until the video has completely buffered.

I have this set up and working in desktop browsers (`preload="auto" gets me mostly where I need to go) but of course mobile browsers don't preload content and require user interaction to start a video buffering.

My question: is it possible, in Mobile Safari, after a user taps Play to *not* have the video start playing *until* it's fully downloaded?

I'm using the [Popcorn](http://popcornjs.org/) HTML5 media framework if it helps any.

Comment: Someone else just asked a very similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645363/xmlhttprequest-to-download-large-html5-video-in-chunks/19648673#19648673

Comment: @brianchirls - nice, I missed that one in my searching for similar threads, good info contained there too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a DOM event called [**`canplaythrough`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#event-media-canplaythrough) that you can subscribe to in your JavaScript. This event is called when the browser estimates it can play through the entire video without pausing to buffer.

**EDIT**: Similarly, you can use the `progress` event to determine how much of the video has been buffered:

```
var player = document.getElementById('video_player'); // The <video> element
player.addEventListener('progress', onVideoProgressUpdate, false);

function onVideoProgressUpdate(e) {
    var percentageBuffered = 0;

    if (player.buffered.length > 0 && player.buffered.end && player.duration) {
        percentageBuffered = player.buffered.end(0) / player.duration;
    } else if (player.bytesTotal != undefined && player.bytesTotal > 0 && player.bufferedBytes != undefined) {
        percentageBuffered = player.bufferedBytes / player.bytesTotal;
    }

    if (percentageBuffered == 1) { // 100% of the video has been buffered
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to know when the browser estimates it can play through, because 1/4 of the way through the video the user might be able to skip to a part near the end. I need to pause the video until every single byte of it has been downloaded, not just the browsers buffer estimate.

Comment: @scottie Updated my answer with a way of determining how much of the video has been buffered.

Comment: Hot damn, lemme give that a go and I'll let you know what happens! Thanks!

Comment: This is doing EXACTLY what I needed it to do, and as a bonus, I can capture the value of `percentageBuffered` to use in creating a progressive loading indicator. Bam! Thank you!