# How to prevent HTML5 looped video from downloading infinitely when cache is disabled

Tags: html, caching, bandwidth, autoplay, ddos

I'm having bandwidth issues.

I have an HTML5 video playing on loop. It automatically starts playing when the visitor lands on the website. It is normally served one time to the user, but what is to prevent anyone from completely disabling cache and the video being served to them again every time it ends and tries to loop?

The reason I ask is because I had google developer console settings open and checked "disable cache when DevTools is open". I walked away from the page for a long time and 10gb of bandwidth was used!  If I could sabotage my bandwidth then I am assuming anyone could.

How can I go about addressing this issue? Here is the HTML5 video code. If you're wondering, the data attributes are for skrollr.js functionality.

```
            <video id="videoOne" autoplay poster="" style="width: 1920px; height: auto; visibility: visible; z-index: 0;" class="landscape desktop"  loop data-anchor-target="#fixTest" data-top="display: block; opacity:1; transform:translateY(0px);" data--70p-top="display: none; opacity:0; transform:translateY(-50px);">
                <source src="img/landVid3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a little bit of JavaScript, you could load the video via an `XMLHttpRequest`. Something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "img/landVid3.mp4", true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function () {
    var video = document.getElementById("videoOne");
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    video.play();
};
xhr.send();
```

Code adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645363/xmlhttprequest-to-download-large-html5-video-in-chunks). Of course, as the answers on the question state, it's much better to set the source of the video to the actual path of the file, but in your situation, you've already done that and decided it's a bad idea.